# How to enable command in the menu ? (Eclipse Plugin)

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin

I created a new command inside a popup menu but it's disabled (not clickable).
What tags should I add to my code in order to enable it on specific files (e.g, xml files) ?

Here is my code :

```xml
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
        <command
            commandId= "test.popup.actions.NewAction"
            label="Run mycommand"
            mnemonic="newAction1"
            tooltip="Do something with this project">
        </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension
```

>

P.S,
I get this warning : **"Referenced identifier 'test.popup.actions.NewAction' in attribute 'commandId' cannot be found"**

Answer (score 1):

You must define the command id using the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point. Something like:

```xml
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        id="test.popup.actions.NewAction"
        description="Command description"
        name="Command name">
  </command>
```

You must then define at least one handler for the command using the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point:

```xml
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
     class="my.package.NewActionHandler"
     commandId="test.popup.actions.NewAction">
  </handler>
```

To make the menu item visible only when XML is selected using the `<visibleWhen>` element of the menu contribution command. Something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
    <command
        commandId= "test.popup.actions.NewAction"
        label="Run mycommand"
        mnemonic="newAction1"
        tooltip="Do something with this project">
       <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="or">
              <test
                    property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                    value="*.xml">
              </test>
           </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
   </command>
```

Lots more information in the Eclipse help (and many other places).

Comment: And where should I write the "enable when right clicked on xml file" code ?

Comment: Added visibleWhen element